# Regarding Ubuntu Software center

Tags: software-center

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 lately and it was working absolutely fine until I opened the Software center to install some apps from the snap. I typed the name of the app I needed and it is not even showing after one hour. It is loading for ages. I can install it through the terminal but I would like to know what happened to the software center.   And also I hope someone could help me with commands on how to install any application without relying on software.

I tried this command

**sudo apt install Spotify**

It did not work.

Comment: spotify is snap, try `snap install spotify`

Comment: Yeah, got it. It worked. Thanks. one more question, Will that command works for other apps also?

Comment: It will work for all apps from the [snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/store). I still prefer `apt` if available...

Comment: Applications can be packaged differently; something packaged as a snap can only be installed with the `snap` command, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you don't install the `snap` version of `Spotify` due to some bugs like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225975/core-dump-error-trying-to-launch-spotify) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/+bug/1873388) that might cause it not to launch, other than the performance issues associated with Snap but rather do this:

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

This is the same client as the snap and you can update it with your usual system update/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion snap is generally a bad idea: it has advantages for packager but only disadvantages for user. I stick to the unix way: If you learn a few commands it is much faster than struggling with sloooow gui. Things like:

```
sudo apt search "what you search for"
sudo apt purge "packename"
```

give you the full power in your hands. I don't miss any software center.